# Library method: Async or not?

Tags: c#, algorithm, async-await, shared-libraries

I have gotten it through my head (perhaps incorrectly) that library methods that take some time should generally be made async.  **Is that true, and if so, how should that be done when there is nothing to await within the library method?**
I am designing my own library with the method:

```
 public  Dictionary<FunctionEnum, double> Evaluate(Func<uint,uint> algorithm, IList<double> 
   suggestedList)
```

It takes in a method that takes a uint and returns a uint and uses that method many times over.  In brief, I'm evaluating the complexity (BigO) of an algorithm by least squares.  For the gory details see:

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/236557/my-c-code-to-evaluate-order-of-algorithm-is-returning-logn-or-n3-instead-of-n?noredirect=1#comment463662_236557

and if my question is better suited for codereview.stackexchange, please tell me.

The method Evaluate takes quite some time because it must call the algorithm method that is passed in many times.  The algorithm method is not async.

I could certainly put the entire loop where algorithm is called inside a Task and await the Task but various articles suggested this is a poor idea (Example: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/Europe/2013/DEV-B318)

In this particular exercise, I have control of some (but not all) of the code that defines algorithms, so the algorithm method could well be defined as:

```
async Task<uint> algorithm(uint) { // perform algorithm }
```

and I'm guessing my signature would become:

```
 public async Task<Dictionary<FunctionEnum, double>> Evaluate(Func<uint,Task<uint>> algorithm, IList<double> 
   suggestedList)
```

In this case, I can certainly make Evaluate async and can certainly call

```
await algorithm((uint) trial[i]);
```

but in general, it's not unreasonable that somebody would want to call my Evaluate method with a non-async method, and I'd like to provide him/her with an estimate that their algorithm is O(N), O(NLogN), etc.
Also, it's not clear (to me) that I could make the algorithm method truly async without introducing a Task in the body of the algorithm method.  Consider for example
uint Fib(uint n) { return the nth Fibonnacci element).
This method could take a long time (for large n), but again, how would one make it an async method?  Introduce something like await Task.Factory.StartNew( () => FibbonaciImplmentation(n); );  ??

Ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: `async` or not is completely opinion based (and you already collected some in the question)… Also how the last "and I'd like to provide him/her with an estimate that their algorithm is O(N), O(NLogN), etc." is related to async/sync question? Also 2 the question you've linked is indeed off-topic on CR, and only 1st of 3 questions could be on-topic on SO (2 is search for libraries and 3 would be duplicate).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, with all due respect, there must be "best practices" for implementing C# libraries.  Especially in regard to what to do about methods that take a long time to complete. Perhaps the caller of the library is responsible for dealing with the problem?  It would not surprise me if there is a document (I could not find it, but that doesn't mean someone doesn't know the location).  Also, were you suggesting that my linked question from codereview is better posted here?  Thanks!

Comment: Not that I know of... Basically you either have your choice made for you by the fact one of the code path is `async` or you have to make your own choice. There are plenty (way too many :) ) opinions online... You may start with MSDN - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async ("... your CPU-bound work is not costly enough compared with the overhead of context switches when multithreading. Every choice has its tradeoff, and you should pick the correct tradeoff for your situation.") more https://www.bing.com/search?q=msdn+when+use+async

Comment: On linked Q from CR - only 1st question ("Do you agree a simple loop 0 to N should be of order N for complexity") may be on-topic for SO, but I doubt it will work well as that's is essentially definition of O(N). You may try to flip the question and ask how to achieve what you want with code you have as example of what you've tried - that probably would be reasonably received... (but brush up on O-notation first - that question about complexity of simple loop is not something one trying to write benchmarking too is expected to have)

Comment: This isn't opinion based. The method is fully synchronous; it doesn't make sense to pass an asynchronous delegate into it (since the method works by timing). So it shouldn't be asynchronous.

Comment: @StephenCleary OP is building some universal "benchmark" too - while I completely agree that indeed one particular instance of an algorithm they want to measure is synchronous (and hence non-async is the answer) it is not clear if all methods they want to measure are synchronous. Looks like question will be re-opened - so please consider to cover that if you decide to answer.

Comment: Thank you for all the comments.  I should probably have mentioned that this all started as "fun project".  I had no idea of the problems I would encounter.   For other problems see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60047196/turning-off-compiler-optimizations-my-c-sharp-code-to-evaluate-order-of-algorit/60047882#60047882

Comment: @StephenCleary, as mentioned this is just a fun project so I have some ability to change things around as I see fit. I control the Evaluate method and the "algorithm" methods that I pass in to Evaluate.  Currently everything is synchronous, but given they take a long time to complete, I was asking if I should make Evaluate or the Algorithm methods (or both) asynchronous, and if so, how to do that. After all, if you think of a simple "find item in list", there is no obvious way to make it asynchronous other than wrapping it in a Task and have await Task.  Thanks for considering my question!

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: That benchmark works by timing execution. Since asynchronous likely means I/O, and since I/O completely destroys CPU timings, I concluded that an asynchronous overload would not be useful.

Comment: @StephenCleary  If I'm reading your comments correctly, perhaps the most direct answer to this question is something like "you are wrong that long duration methods in a library should be made async (the first sentence of question).  If there is no I/O or async methods within the method, just make it synchronous and make the caller deal with it as he sees fit".  Perhaps this is a simple thing that is covered in a CS degree or there is a Microsoft document.  I'm afraid I'm self taught and it's not immediately obvious to me what is the best practice.  Thanks!

Comment: @Dave: Yes, that is exactly what I mean. If a method is not naturally asynchronous (generally I/O), then it should be synchronous. How long it runs is immaterial. [The caller may decide to run it on a thread pool thread and consume it asynchronously if it wants to, but that decision should be left up to the caller](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/taskrun-etiquette-and-proper-usage.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The method Evaluate takes quite some time because it must call the algorithm method that is passed in many times. The algorithm method is not async.

The `Evaluate` method works by timing execution. Since "asynchronous" usually means I/O, and since I/O is orders of magnitude slower than CPU execution (the actual algorithm being measured), I do not believe an asynchronous overload would be useful.

> I could certainly put the entire loop where algorithm is called inside a Task and await the Task but various articles suggested this is a poor idea

A naturally-synchronous method should be synchronous. It doesn't matter how long it takes to run.

If `Evaluate` is run by a UI application, and it wants to keep its UI responsive, it can [call the `Evaluate` method wrapped in a `Task.Run`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html).

Comment: Thank you once again Stephen.  Great answer.  I'd like to think I could have avoided asking the question if I'd seen your link: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/taskrun-etiquette-and-proper-usage.html before writing this question.  Unfortunately I didn't find it in my searching.  Perhaps that link and this question/answer will help some future person.